# Composer install not executed by user data from AWS Launch Configuration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, autoscaling, user-data

I have created an AWS Launch Configuration with following user data

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
git clone git@github.com:[MyUserName]/[project-name].git /var/www/[project-name]
cd /var/www/[project-name]
composer install --no-dev
php artisan migrate
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod g+w -R /var/www
```

Now every line gets executed, except `composer install --no-dev`. But if I run the above script manually everything works fine. So can anyone please help me understand what is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried explicitly providing the path to `composer`, i.e. `/usr/bin/composer install` or something along those lines?

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried that, It didn't work. For me its `/usr/local/bin/composer install`